Nest.js - Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `...` using `parserOptions.project`: <tsconfigRootDir>/tsconfig.json
I created a fresh new nest.js project using:
nest new myapp
I created some modules, services, controllers:
nest g module product; nest g service product; nest g controller product;
But in all files I'm getting this error:


Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on
~/tutorials/nodejs/typeorm/simple-app/src/photo/photo.entity.ts
using parserOptions.project: /tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:

Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
Change that TSConfig to include this file
Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project See the typescript-eslint docs for more info:
https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-fileeslin


My eslint configuration file:
.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js',],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
};

My tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}


I solved my problem adding ecmaVersion parameter inside .eslintrc.js:
module.exports = {
  ecmaVersion: 15,
  ...

